# How to install the C functions for the python package bintrees?

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, binary-tree

I want to use the python package bintrees:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/2.0.2

I install it on my centos through pip:
pip install bintrees

When I import the bintrees in the python, I got these warning:

> > > import bintrees
> > >       Warning: FastBinaryTree not available, using Python version BinaryTree.
> > >       Warning: FastAVLTree not available, using Python version AVLTree.
> > >       Warning: FastRBTree not available, using Python version RBTree.

I want to use the FastRBTree, but I don't know how to install it. On the homepage of the bintrees, I saw this:

Compiling the fast Trees requires Cython and on Windows is a C-Compiler necessary (MingW works fine).

But no other hint about how to install the fast Trees (the C-functions).

Could anyone let me know how to install the C-fuctions of the bintrees package?

Answer (score 1):

As you've already said, you need Cython.

On CentOS you can do

```
pip install cython
```

and then reinstall bintrees:

```
pip uninstall bintrees
pip install bintrees
```

Answer (score 0):

> > > from bintrees import BinaryTree   #only BinartTree
> > >
> > > from bintrees import *       #all

Comment: Hi, I tried both of the two import method you provided, and both of the report the same warning:<code>
    Warning: FastBinaryTree not available, using Python version BinaryTree.
    Warning: FastAVLTree not available, using Python version AVLTree.
    Warning: FastRBTree not available, using Python version RBTree.<code>
So seems the problem is still exist: I can't use the C-function, only can use the python implement.